# Regex from special characters "/*" to "*/"

Tags: .net, regex

I'm quite new with regex. (.net)
I need a regular expression which selects anything from `/* to */` (including /* and */).
My Problem - is that i'm not able to get the right expressen with these special characters.
With standard strings it works fine.
Once more... it should select over linebreaks. 
i.e.:

```
text
/*
some text
*/
text
```

the result should be:

```
/*
some text
*/
```

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: hi - iv tried with strings - never got it with special characters ending /*   ...mine was:
(?=/*).*(?<=2ndstring)

Comment: `/\*.*\*/` Singleline,ExplicitCapture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `*` : `/\*.*?\*/`
And use the `Singleline` option so the `.` (dot) matches break lines.

You can access the matched content like this :

```
string value;
string pattern = @"/\*.*?\*/"
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
if( match.Success )
{
  value = match.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work: `Regex.Match("/*hello*/", "^(/\*(.*?)\*/)$", RegexOptions.SingleLine)`

Comment: thanks - it works if /* */ are in one line, a linebreak and the regex dont work anymore...

Comment: hmm - seems that the RegexOptions.Multiline has no effect in that case - if i write a single line you expression works fine - mutliline seems to be ignored

Comment: Hmm ... Always forget which one is which but in any case, I edited the answer for anyone who might come in later on :)

Comment: ahh sinlge line ;) - thank you very much - but polkduran was a litte bit faster with the SingleLine Option.... gave you 1 up